# How to loop through a list of matrices and compute the matrix inverse of each element (lapply)?

Tags: r

Good afternoon !

Under R, i developped the following code :

```
            k=10
            w_k=rep(1,k)/k
            n_j=rep(0,k)
            
            print(w_k)
            
            data=as.matrix(iris[1:150,-5])
            means=sample(1:dim(data)[1],k,replace=FALSE)
            mu=as.matrix(iris[means,-5])
            sigma=cov(data)
            sigma_list=rep(list(sigma),k)
            
            P_Cj_Xi<-function(Xi,mu,sigma_list=sigma_list){
            k=length(Xi) 
            n_j=rep(0,k) 
            r=lapply(1:k, function(i) r[i]=solve(matrix(unlist(sigma_list[i]),ncol=k)))  
      
# lapply isn't storing the solve(matrix(unlist(sigma_list[i]),ncol=k)) from 1 to k 
# try print(solve(matrix(unlist(sigma_list[i]),ncol=k))) , the inverse 
# is correctly computed. I need to access each of inverses .
                

            }
        # example of run :
        P_Cj_Xi(Xi=data[1,],mu,sigma_list=sigma_list)
```

The `sigma_list` is a list that contains `k=10` of matrices. All of those matrices are initially equal to `sigma=cov(data)`. I need to loop through `sigma_list` and compute the inverse of each matrix in this list. Those calculated inverse matrices should be stored in another list `r`.

With the previous code , i'm usually getting this error :

```
Warning message in r[i] = solve(matrix(unlist(sigma_list[i]), ncol = k)):
"le nombre d'objets à remplacer n'est pas multiple de la taille du remplacement"
Warning message in r[i] = solve(matrix(unlist(sigma_list[i]), ncol = k)):
"le nombre d'objets à remplacer n'est pas multiple de la taille du remplacement"
Warning message in r[i] = solve(matrix(unlist(sigma_list[i]), ncol = k)):
"le nombre d'objets à remplacer n'est pas multiple de la taille du remplacement"
Warning message in r[i] = solve(matrix(unlist(sigma_list[i]), ncol = k)):
"le nombre d'objets à remplacer n'est pas multiple de la taille du remplacement"
```

I hope my question is clear . Thank you for help in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should create an empty matrix with `r=matrix(NA,length(Xi),length(Xi))` then i could repeate `r` a number of times `=n_clusters`

```
  P_Cj_Xi<-function(Xi,mu,sigma_list=sigma_list,n_clusters=k){
    k=n_clusters
    n_j=rep(0,length(Xi))  
    r=matrix(NA,length(Xi),length(Xi))    
    r=rep(list(r),n_clusters )    
    r=lapply(1:n_clusters , function(i) r[[i]]=solve(matrix(unlist(sigma_list[i]),ncol=length(Xi))))  
    r
            
    #n_j=sapply(1:k, function(i) -1/2*(Xi-mu[i])%*%r[i]%*%(t(Xi-mu[i])))          
    #n_j    
    }
    
    P_Cj_Xi(Xi=data[1,],mu,sigma_list=sigma_list)
```